# Using Angular 2 two-way data binding with Polymer

Tags: typescript, polymer, angular

I'm trying to combine Polymer elements with Angular 2 and I struggle with the two-way data binding aspect.

As an example I use paper-tabs and display the tab number that is currently in use. Whenever I change a tab, I want that change to happen in a tabNr field in the AppComponent as well. Whenever I click on the tab number that is being displayed, I want the number to change and change the tab accordingly. My initial approach was this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <paper-tabs [(selected)]="tabNr">
                        <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
                    </paper-tabs>
                </paper-toolbar>
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <div (click)="traverse()">Tab {{tabNr + 1}}</div>
                </paper-toolbar>
                `
})
export class AppComponent {
    tabNr = 0;

    traverse() {
        this.tabNr = (this.tabNr + 1) % 3;
    }

}
```

However, this does not work. I can't change the tabs. I can click the Tab number being displayed to change that, but that is also not reflected in the actual tabs. In the following I'll focus on that line in the code to discuss all other possibilities I tried out:

```
<paper-tabs [(selected)]="tabNr">
```

I was expecting that one way data-binding (paper-tabs going to the AppComponent) would work like this

```
<paper-tabs (selected)="tabNr">
```

but that doesn't work. To actually get the changes to register, I need to use the event from Polymer like this:

```
<paper-tabs selected="tabNr" (selected-changed)="tabNr=$event.detail.value">
```

That defeats the purpose of using Angular 2 for the bindings. It seems to me that the problem here is, that polymer is firing a different event for the change than whatever Angular 2 is expecting.

In order to get the click-changes to register with the tabs I have to do this:

```
<paper-tabs [attr.selected]="tabNr">
```

However, I cannot combine both of those result into this

```
<paper-tabs [attr.selected]="tabNr" (selected-changed)="tabNr=$event.detail.value">
```

because I get the following exception whenever I change a tab:

> EXCEPTION: Expression 'tabNr in AppComponent@2:17' has changed after
>   it was checked. Previous value: '1'. Current value: '1' in [tabNr in
>   AppComponent@2:17]

I assume there is probably some sort of circular event firing going on. I can solve this by using a method for the (selected-changed) event that only changes it if the number of the event is actually a different number, but that whole approach seems cumbersome and I derived quite a bit from simply using [()] to bind the data.

So my question is:
Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The right way to for two-way binding is

```
<paper-tabs [attr.selected]="tabNr" (selected-changed)="updateTab($event)">
```

or

```
<paper-tabs attr.selected="{{tabNr}}" (selected-changed)="updateTab($event)">
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCdmz8iZZXAFK0n3d2Yt?p=preview)

To avoid the "expression has changed since it was last checked" warning I had to parse the `event.detail.value` to `number`.

For

```
<paper-tabs [(selected)]="tabNr">
```

to work Polymer would need to send a different event `selectedChange` instead of `selected-changed` and the event would need to be the value `1` instead of a custom event.

Comment: I tried your solution in plunkr. It does not look like it is working, maybe you could fix this accordingly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KCIWywLOi9YgbA44d9dq?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, seems I saw your comment before you added the Plunker link. And I was wrong. The binding works only with `attr.`. For more details see my updated answer with the updated Plunker.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work without calling a function?

Besides that, I've found another plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/1ZOmXJxRnGU89d1mg5lu?p=preview) that seems to work with your first solution.
Unfortunately, I am not really sure what is the difference to our current plunker.

Comment: You can use a string instead of number, then you don't need to call `parseFloat()` for the changed event but then you need it in the `traverse()` method. I'll have a look at the Plunker later.

Comment: Seems to work without `attr.` in both plunkers today :-/